# How do I get CSS to display on my pages?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I'm creating my first Wordpress theme - got so far as creating a loop so that pages can be created and content posted dynamically.

Now I'm stuck because whilst the website looks good on the home page, when I click to load a sample page I've created, whilst the nav bar loads with the CSS, the actual content part of the page has no CSS and I don't know how to make this load.

Here's my page.php file:

```
        <?php 
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );



            endwhile; endif; 
        ?>

    </div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

And my content.php is simply:

Anyone know how I get it so that the custom pages load my custom CSS?

Comment: Did you included header in your page.php ?

Comment: Have you enqueued the Stylesheets within your `functions.php` file?

Comment: Will want to include footer while you're at it. get_header(); at top of file, get_footer(); at the bottom.

Comment: I haven't included header or footer because my header included my <h1> which I only want displaying on the homepage - so I made a nav.php and linked this since this is all I want showing on the pages - that and the content I insert dynamically but displayed in the CSS which is linked in the <head>. However despite that <head> being a part of the nav.php I have linked to, it doesn't load anything.

Comment: I don't have a functions.php file. I've been following a tutorial and they didn't use one in that

Comment: Why not just load the header and footer and use is_home() to only display the content you want on the homepage?